# Spring Retry does not work on 2nd level of methods

Tags: java, spring

`@Retryable` doesn't seem to be working on 2nd level of methods as in `sphRemoteCall` below. I see that a proxy is created but it is never retried on failures.

Once I moved `@Retryable` to the 1st level of methods like  `getSubscriberAccount`, it's started working.

Example below:

```
@Service
public class SphIptvClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    //Works over here
    @Retryable(maxAttempts=3, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100))
    public GetSubscriberAccountResponse getSubscriberAccount(String loginTocken, String billingServId) {

        GetSubscriberAccountResponse response = (GetSubscriberAccountResponse) sphRemoteCall(sphIptvEndPoint, getSubAcc, "xxxxx");
        return response;
    }

    /*
     * Retryable is not working on the 2nd level methods in the bean. 
     * It works only with methods which are called directly from outside
     * if there is 2nd level method, like this, Retryable is not working.
     */
    //@Retryable
    private Object sphRemoteCall(String uri, Object requestPayload, String soapAction) {
        log.debug("Calling the sph for uri:{} and soapAction:{}", uri, soapAction);
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, requestPayload, new SoapActionCallback(soapAction));
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class SphClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public SphIptvClient sphIptvClient() {
        SphIptvClient client = new SphIptvClient();
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is due how Spring AOP works. It uses proxies and only method calls going into the object are proxied, if you put it on a private or internally called method it won't pass through the proxy and thus no AOP.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: you the real mvp, I spent 2 hours trying to understand how it works

Comment: You achieve this using custom retry templates.  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry#retrytemplate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So this is a super late answer, but since I've just come here and confronted the same problem (again, after years ago wrestling with transactions) I'll furnish a little more fleshed out solution and hopefully someone will find it useful. Suffice to say that [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)'s diagnosis is correct.

[image]

[image]

In the above case, and to paraphrase [Understanding AOP proxies](https://web.archive.org/web/20180223173052/https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), any place where `SphIptvClient` gets autowired will be given a reference to a proxy which Spring Retry will create when `@EnableRetry` is handled:

> "The `@EnableRetry` annotation creates proxies for `@Retryable` beans" - [Declarative Retry - Spring Retry](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909175924/https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#declarative-retry)

Once `getSubscriberAccount` has been invoked and execution has passed through the proxy and into the `@Service` instance of the object, no reference to the proxy is known. As a result `sphRemoteCall` is called as if there were no `@Retryable` at all.

You could work with the framework by shuffling code around in such a way as to allow `getSubscriberAccount` to call a proxy-ed `sphRemoteCall`, which requires a new interface and class implementation.

For example:

```
public interface SphWebService {
   Object sphRemoteCall(String uri, Object requestPayload, String soapAction);
}

@Component
public class SphWebServiceImpl implements SphWebService {
   @Retryable
   public Object sphRemoteCall(String uri, Object requestPayload, String soapAction) {
       log.debug("Calling the sph for uri:{} and soapAction:{}", uri, soapAction);
       return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, requestPayload, new SoapActionCallback(soapAction));
   }
}

@Service
public class SphIptvClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

   @Autowired
   SphWebService sphWebService;

   @Retryable(maxAttempts=3, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100))
   public GetSubscriberAccountResponse getSubscriberAccount(String loginTocken, String billingServId) {
       GetSubscriberAccountResponse response = (GetSubscriberAccountResponse) this.sphWebService.sphRemoteCall(sphIptvEndPoint, getSubAcc, "xxxxx");
       return response;
   }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class SphClientConfig {
   // the @Bean method was unnecessary and may cause confusion. 
   // @Service was already instantiating SphIptvClient behind the scenes.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Retryable only works on the methods when called directly from other classes.
If you will try to invoke one method with @Retryable annotation from some other method of the same class, it will eventually not work.

```
    // any call from this method to test method will not invoke the retry logic.
    public void yetAnotherMethod() {
        this.test();
    }

    // it will work
    @Retryable(value = {RuntimeException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1500))
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Count: " + count++);
        throw new RuntimeException("testing");
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover() {
        System.out.println("Exception occured.");
    }
```

So, the output if test method is called, will be:

Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
Exception occured.

But, if the yetAnotherMethod is called, output will be:
Count: 0
And a Runtime exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a method which calls certain API - **callAPI()** and you want to implement retry logic over it, you can try use a `do while`, as it will execute only once, if successful.

Method to hit the external API

```
public int callAPI() { 
    return 1; 
}
```

Method to implement retry logic

```
public int retrylogic()  throws InterruptedException {
    int retry = 0;
    int status = -1;
    boolean delay = false;
    do {
         // adding a delay, if you want some delay between successive retries
        if (delay) {   
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        // Call the actual method, and capture the response, 
        // and also catch any exception which occurs during the call.
        // (Network down/ endpoint not avaliable
        try {
            status = callAPI();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
            status = -1;
        }
        finally {
            switch (status) { //now based on error response or any exception you retry again

            case HTTPStatus.OK:
                System.out.println("OK");
                return status; 
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown response code");
                break;
            }
            retry++;
            System.out.println("Failed retry " + retry + "/" + 3);
            delay = true;

        } 
    }while (retry < 3);
    return status;
}
```