# Retry the call if server is down in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest, retry-logic

I am trying to implement the retry logic or mechanism on micro-services to micro-services call. Basically, have to attempt retry 2 times if server is down only.

I tried to use @Retryable and @Recover to perform same but no luck. Instead I can thought of to use try-catch to catch particular exception when server is down, but I am not aware which exception will work and I can use it in try-catch to attempt retry 2 times when server is down.

Moreover, I checked and hence found for such cases there is `ResourceAccessException` which basically made for when server is down but I am not sure.

Your help will be most appreciated. Please guide me here.

Comment: What about a simple loop?

Comment: what is @Retry, I do not find such thing in Java/Spring

Comment: Typo mistake, have rectified it now

Comment: @Retryable will not work on private methods, ie, if a method is called from within the same class (because of how Spring proxies work), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585089/spring-retry-does-not-work-on-2nd-level-of-methods

Answer (score 1):

Spring `@Retryable` should do the job

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

NB: `@EnableRetry` is important

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `Circuit Breaker` with Spring Boot. Circuit Breakers allow you to manage the error in the event of both a retry and an error.

Here are some Circuit Breakers that you can use with Spring Boot:

- [Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker)
- [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix)
- [Resillence4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3)